# Usage of pascal variant record

Tags: pascal, freepascal

I need help from those who know the pascal very well.

I need (teachers requirement) to use a variant record. Those variant record are defined like this:

```
Temperature = record
   case scale :   TemperatureScale of
   celsius : (celsius_value : ScaleCelsius);
   kelvin : (kelvin_value : ScaleKelvin);
end;
```

According to primary sources I found during my research about this topic, I could not find how to use variant record, only how to declare it.

My primary sources: google search(found nothing), [Case-Freepascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Case) and [Record-Freepascal](http://wiki.freepascal.org/Record)

Edit for those who wonder what i  must use in implementation it is exacly this:

```
 type
  UkPolozka = ^Polozka;
  UkHodnota = ^Hodnota;
  TypUdaj=(typretez, typcele, typrealne, typlogik, typpole, typobjekt);

  VarZaznam = record
  case Udaj: TypUdaj of        
    typretez:  (retez: string);
    typcele:   (cele: word);
    typrealne: (realne: single);
    typlogik:  (logik: boolean);
    typpole:   (pole: UkHodnota);
    typobjekt: (objekt: UkPolozka);
 end;

 Polozka = record
    Nazev: string;
    Hodn:  VarZaznam;
    Dalsi: UkPolozka
 end;
 Hodnota = record
    Hodn:  VarZaznam;
    Dalsi: UkHodnota     
 end;
```

Comment: You have not described specific problem. Consider https://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/rtl/sysutils/longrec.html as example of useful variant record

Comment: If record field `scale` is `celsius`, the variant part contains the `celsius_value`. If it is `kelvin`, then the variant part contains the `kelvin_value`. The variant part shares room for multiple interpretations depending on the variant descriptor. The variant descriptor can also be specified as a type only. `case boolean of`.

Comment: @mbo how figure type of record? and how read from it?

Comment: Surely this is all covered in your lessons and your text books.

Comment: @DavidHeffernan nope... it is not.... teacher breafly mentioned it during class 3 or more weeks ago ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider example record from [Delphi Help](http://docwiki.embarcadero.com/RADStudio/Tokyo/en/Structured_Types_(Delphi)#Variant_Parts_in_Records). I modified it with tag.

Tag usage is optional and usually is not used and doesn't provide useful information.
Note that the first line outputs radius with the same value as height - they share the same memory.

Then I explicitly set tag (but fields stay the same)

Also note size difference for no-tag record and tagged one.

Note again - in most cases programmers don't define or use tag value. It might be unsafe to rely on tag (until you follow strict rules in assigning tags). I did not set `rectangle` tag, but program consider zero tag as the first variant.

Just assign needed field by name. Just read needed field by name. For your example `varVarZaznam.retez:= 'test';`

```
type
   TShapeList = (Rectangle, Triangle, Circle, Ellipse, Other);
   TFigure = record
     case shape: TShapeList of
       Rectangle: (Height, Width: Real);
       Triangle: (Side1, Side2, Angle: Real);
       Circle: (Radius: Real);
       Ellipse, Other: ();
   end;

   TFigureNoTag = record
     case TShapeList of
       Rectangle: (Height, Width: Real);
       Triangle: (Side1, Side2, Angle: Real);
       Circle: (Radius: Real);
       Ellipse, Other: ();
   end;

var
   Fig: TFigure;
begin
  Fig.Height := 5;
  Fig.Width := 3;
  //default tag is zero = Rectangle
  if Fig.shape = Rectangle then
    Writeln('Rect ', Fig.Height:3:0, Fig.Width:3:0, Fig.Radius:3:0)
  else
    Writeln('not Rect');

  Fig.shape := Circle;
  if Fig.shape <> Rectangle then
    Writeln('not Rect');

  Writeln('Fig size ', SizeOf(TFigure), ' noTag size ', SizeOf(TFigureNoTag));
  Readln;
```

output in Delphi:

```
Rect   5  3  5
not Rect
Fig size 32 noTag size 24
```

Comment: this seem preatty good example...  and also legit i probably will need to set tags because i will store it into memory in one big dinamic structure(requirement of teacher) and do stuff with it...  and also i need to know how to set tag

Comment: The tag is simply a field. Set it like any other field in a record.

Comment: My example contains tag setting `Fig.shape := Circle;`

Comment: "Tag usage is optional and usually is not used and doesn't provide useful information"  Wrong.